# How can I avoid eslint error (Unexpected chained assignment no-multi-assign) in the code generated by typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I have a .ts file where I have defined and exported two functions as follows:

```js
export const foo = () => { ... }

export const bar = () => { ... }
```

The code works as expected and I am able to import these functions to other files.

However, when I run lint, eslint throws an error `Unexpected chained assignment  no-multi-assign`

The compiled javascript code in fact shows chained assignment as follows:

```js
exports.foo = exports.bar = void 0;
```

I could specify a eslint rule to disable the error, but I was wondering if someone could help me understand if I should be doing something differently to write a better syntax.

Note I also tried following with same result:

```js
const foo = () => { ... }
const bar = () => { ... }

export {foo, bar}
```

Comment: Only lint source files, not transpiled/compiled files. For similar reasons, you don't try to lint minified files, do you? Your code is fine.

Comment: Ah! Rookie mistake. Thank you.